# Diff Folders Without Diffing Files

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux: Compare Directory Structure Without Comparing Files](https://superuser.com/questions/166317/linux-compare-directory-structure-without-comparing-files)

I am diff-ing two folder trees, but it takes a long time because it is diff-ing the files themselves.  I just want to know what folders/files are in one tree and not the other.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/166317/linux-compare-directory-structure-without-comparing-files

Comment: That was comparing, this is diff-ing.

Comment: @Jonah - are you asking how to do it, specifically with diff, when the other question was open to other tools and commands?

Comment: Using diff would be good, but if it can't do it other tools are just fine.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you're making between "comparing" and "diffing".  The solution that you accepted in the other question used diff as a final step, and should tell you "what folders/files are in one tree and not the other".  Can you clarify what you need that it doesn't give you?

Comment: Ah, I was confused as to how the provided bash script works (I'm evidently new to this), and was running it with a typo.  The output was strange, and I thought it was for a side by side comparison or something.  I'll delete this question.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `find` to list the files in each tree, sort them, then use `diff` or `comm` for comparison. The little-known `comm` command is a specialized file comparison tool that just distinguishes lines appearing only in the first file, lines appearing only in the second file and lines appearing in both files.

```
(cd /some/dir1 && find . | sort >/tmp/dir1.find)
(cd /where/dir2 && find . | sort >/tmp/dir2.find)
# Show the files that are in dir1 but not in dir2
comm -23 /tmp/dir1.find /tmp/dir2.find
# Show the files that are in dir2 but not in dir1
comm -13 /tmp/dir1.find /tmp/dir2.find
```