# Bash printf: what does format specifier %P mean?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell-script, bash-scripting

The `printf` statement :

`find directory1 -type d -printf "%P\n" | sort > file1`

in the answer https://superuser.com/a/166322/856910 includes a format specifier `%P`. From the output of this command, I find that it removes the `./` at the beginning of a line: from `./foo` to `foo`. What is the exact meaning of this specifier? I can't find it from `man printf`.

Comment: What man page exactly? The answer that states "read the `man find`, not `man printf`" is good, but I think you may have confused *three* `printf`s, not only two. The title mentions "Bash printf". In Bash `printf` is a builtin. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1306762/432690). `man bash` (or `help printf` in Bash) describes the builtin. The builtin is the only `printf` I would call "Bash printf". If by "man page" you meant `man printf`, then it's about another `printf`, mostly equivalent, still separate. Finally the `-printf` action of your `find` is yet another entity.

Comment: (cont'd) A remote possibility is you meant `man find`, but somehow `man find` in your OS describes a different implementation of `find` than you actually run. Unlikely, as in this case you would probably write "find printf", not "Bash printf" in the title. Anyway, what man page do you mean exactly? Please [edit] the question and clarify.

Comment: I mean `man printf`, so yes, I am confused by the parameters, thinking that it's the "format specifier" of `printf` instead of parameter of `find`. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the `man find`, not `man printf` or `man bash`/`help printf`.

> %P     File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was found removed.

Answer (score 0):

`%P` means "the file path with the starting point removed." Thus, it removes the `./` as you have found.

Comment: You need to add more details as your answer is almsot the same as the earlier one above.